# How to scroll while Holding Shift to copy in tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux, mouse, xterm, scrolling

I have Mouse mode set to on in Tmux so that I can make use of the scroll wheel using `set-window-option -g mode-mouse on`.

However if I want to copy the output of a particular command which spans more than the height of the terminal window, **I can't scroll down while holding the shift key.**

What modifications do I need to make to the configuration file in order to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/537470/tmux-mouse-select-and-scroll-at-the-same-time and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398716/mouse-scrolling-and-selection-in-terminal-with-tmux

Answer (score 1):

Probably you cannot.  xterm (and the programs which act like it) makes a distinction between mouse operations with/without the <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier:

- the ***unshifted*** operations can be programmed, i.e., an application can send an escape sequence telling xterm to send back escape sequences for each mouse click.
- the ***unshifted*** operations cannot be programmed in this way.  They are left as-is.

So `tmux` is not likely to be able to change this behavior.  Further, the way the mouse buttons are used is (again, an old convention) in the way: one button acts to start a selection, another to extend the selection and the third to paste the selection.  Some terminals may implement *dragging* if you hold down the extend-selection button.

But the wheel mouse is (really) much newer than the rest of the protocol, probably from the mid/late-1990s.  In the mouse protocol, it sends fake button events, e.g., buttons 4 and 5.  While a terminal *could* be implemented to extend a selection using the wheel mouse, `tmux` has no way to control that—and it likely would be built-in/not-configurable.  If you are not seeing the desired behavior already, you probably cannot get it.

The distinction with <kbd>shift</kbd> is very old, and not confined to mouse operations: on some platforms, the <kbd>page-up</kbd> and <kbd>page-down</kbd> keys are setup to *scroll* the terminal when the <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier is added, while the unshifted keys may be read from an application.

Further reading:

- [Wheel mice](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Wheel-mice) (XTerm Control Sequences)
- [Normal tracking mode](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Normal-tracking-mode) (XTerm Control Sequences)
- [Default Key Bindings](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) XTerm manual, e.g., the bindings for mouse-buttons

  ```
                     ~Meta <Btn1Down>:select-start() \n\
                   ~Meta <Btn1Motion>:select-extend() \n\
                 ~Ctrl ~Meta <Btn2Up>:insert-selection(SELECT, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
               ~Ctrl ~Meta <Btn3Down>:start-extend() \n\
                   ~Meta <Btn3Motion>:select-extend() \n\
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I would like to add that having `set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` in the config file gave me what I was looking for but at the cost of some keyboard functionality. Like I couldn't use arrow keys or page up page down keys with it and scrolling long text with mouse is a bit tedious so I went back with the defaults.